# Quicksort Stack overflow error

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, quicksort

while practicing for an exam I encountered a (for me) strange issue with quicksort.

My implementation:

```
    public void quicksort(int l, int r)
{
    if(l<r && l>0 && r<=array.length-1)
    {
        int pivot = array[pivot(l, r)];
        int i = l;
        int j = r;
        if(j==i+1)
        {
            if(array[i]>array[j])
            {
                System.out.println(array[i]+"<->"+array[j]);
                int help = array[i];      
                array[i] = array[j];  
                array[j] = help;    
            }
        }
        else{ while(i<=j)
            {
                if(array[i]>=pivot && pivot>= array[j])
                {
                    System.out.println(array[i]+">="+pivot+">="+array[j]);

                    int help = array[i];      
                    array[i] = array[j];  
                    array[j] = help;
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
                else{
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if(l<j && j<array.length-1)quicksort(l, j);
            if(i<r)quicksort(i, r);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is giving me a "Java.lang.StackOverflowError: null" in (here) Line 34. This Error can, however, be avoided by swapping j with j-1 and i with j in Lines 34 and 35. I really tried everything that came into my mind, but I really cannot come up with a solution :/

Comment: which is the expected input-output?

Comment: Instead of using the callstack, use a stack collection. Create one, since java's only impl of a stack is synchronized.

Comment: the int array "array" is defined in another method.

l is the left and r the right border element of the current list. both are int values as they are used as index for the int array.

Comment: ...and why is it not a parameter to the function?

Comment: Do you mean the pivot element?

Comment: I haven't worked it through but the almost certain cause is 'runaway recursion'. You method calls itself and I expect you'll find one of the two conditions it does that is always true so it just calls itself and calls itself and calls itself until it exhausts the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are much better implementations of quicksort, here is my attempt with commentary which will hopefully help you remember it better:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] theArray, int left, int right) {
    //we declare 2 variables   
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    //we calculate a pivot, simply taking the middle value of the array
    int pivot = theArray[(left+right)/2];

    //check that i hasn't gone beyond j (i starts at 0, j starts at array.length)
    while(i<=j){
        //if here, must mean i is less-than or equal to j, so check to see if
        //the array value i is less than our pivot
        while(theArray[i] < pivot){
            //if it is less-than pivot, the value theArray[i] is in correct place
            //so we can increment i to go to next 
            i++;
        }
        //now do exactly same thing for j, however, j starts at array.length, so decrement
        while(theArray[j] > pivot){
            j--;
        }
        //if we are here, it likely means we need to swap values
        //check that i hasn't gone beyond j
        if(i<=j){
            //simple swap
            temp = theArray[i];
            theArray[i] = theArray[j];
            theArray[j] = temp;
            //we just swapped values, so we don't need to check them again, so continue
            i++; 
            j--;
        }
    }
    //now check if parameter left is < j 
    //if left has gone beyond j, it means we no longer need to further sort
    if(left<j){
        //rinse and repeat
        quickSort(theArray, left, j);
    //and check that i is still less than right parameter 
    }if(i < right){
        //rinse and repeat
        quickSort(theArray, i, right);
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
//you can amend this code so you don't have to pass in an array
quickSort(theArray, 0, theArray.length-1);
```

It's fairly simple once you understand what quicksort is trying to do. Don't stress out about it, take a 15minute break, watch a graphical representation of the algorithm and think about how the code should behave and what it's trying to achieve. Come back here, look at the code, and start implementing it. Rinse and repeat! Good luck!

Also (not sure how your exam layout is) but you could also mention that to near-enough guarantee runtime of O(n log n), you really ought to [shuffle the array](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/) before hand.

Comment: Understanding quicksort is not my problem. My problem is the recursion not doing what it is supposed to do, and strangely your code gives me exactly the same error as mine does.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: Never mind. Now it is doing what it should do. Just added brackets around the recursion and both examples (mine and yours) are working just fine.

Comment: That's odd but I'm glad you figured it out. What JDK version are you running and how you compiling the code?